# Can I use a QPainter to draw a line with a per-vertex color?

Tags: qt5, qpainter

I have a custom Qt 5 widget that renders itself using `QPainter`. I would like to be able to draw a line where each vertex is associated with a different color, and the color is interpolated accordingly along the lines joining the points. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to perform the drawing on a line-by-line basis.  Assuming that's acceptable then a [`QPen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html) initialized with a suitable [`QLinearGradient`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineargradient.html) should work...

```
class widget: public QWidget {
  using super = QWidget;
public:
  explicit widget (QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    : super(parent)
    {
    }
protected:
  virtual void paintEvent (QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
      super::paintEvent(event);
      QPainter painter(this);

      /*
       * Define the corners of a rectangle lying 10 pixels inside
       * the current bounding rect.
       */
      int left = 10, right = width() - 10;
      int top = 10, bottom = height() - 10;
      QPoint top_left(left, top);
      QPoint top_right(right, top);
      QPoint bottom_right(right, bottom);
      QPoint bottom_left(left, bottom);

      /*
       * Insert the points along with their required colours into
       * a suitable container.
       */
      QVector<QPair<QPoint, QColor>> points;
      points << qMakePair(top_left, Qt::red);
      points << qMakePair(top_right, Qt::green);
      points << qMakePair(bottom_right, Qt::blue);
      points << qMakePair(bottom_left, Qt::black);
      for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
        int e = (i + 1) % points.size();

        /*
         * Create a suitable linear gradient based on the colours
         * required for vertices indexed by i and e.
         */
        QLinearGradient gradient;
        gradient.setColorAt(0, points[i].second);
        gradient.setColorAt(1, points[e].second);
        gradient.setStart(points[i].first);
        gradient.setFinalStop(points[e].first);

        /*
         * Set the pen and draw the line.
         */
        painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(gradient), 10.0f));
        painter.drawLine(points[i].first, points[e].first);
      }
    }
};
```

The above results in something like...

[image]

(Note: There may be a better way to achieve this using [`QPainterPath`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) and [`QPainterPathStroker`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpathstroker.html) but I'm not sure based on the docs. I've looked at.)